# Не выполняется js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

В контроллере

```
**line_items_controller.rb**

class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        session[:counter] = 0
        format.html { redirect_to store_url }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_url }
      format.js
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

end
```

выполняется js при методе create (/app/views/line_items/create.js), но не выполняется при  destroy (/app/views/line_items/destroy.js), при этом метод работает верно - после обновления страницы всё как должно быть.

destroy.js:

```
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
```

Вызов:

```
<%= button_to '-', line_item, method: :delete,  confirm: 'Are you sure?', remote: true %>
```

В консоли хрома ошибка:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/line_items/69 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8725
send jquery.js:8725
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:8155
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js:73
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js:149
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js:356
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:5117
elemData.handle jquery.js:4788
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну наверное в метод `destroy` контроллера надо добавить переменную @cart:

```
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
```

Валиться то скорее всего на том что render nil....

И не `destroy.js` а `destroy.js.erb`

P.S. Если internal server error (500) при запросе - то смотрите логи сервера

Comment: Переменную пробовал - не помогло. В логах в консоли:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template line_items/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/syntaxys/sites/AWD4/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:83:in `destroy'


  Rendered /home/syntaxys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.3ms)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что рельсы ругаются на отсутствие вьюхи /home/syntaxys/sites/AWD4/app/views/destroy.html.erb?

Comment: @Лисёнок, да, правильно

Comment: Создал destroy.html.erb:

    <%= render @cart %>

Стал ругаться на render nil, как указал выше Чад. Добавил переменную @cart в метод delete контроллера, все заработало, 500 ошибки нет, в логе консоли:

    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 23:07:11 +0400
    Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
    Cart Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
    Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY title
    Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (46.0ms)

Comment: (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = 23
    Rendered collection (0.0ms)
    Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (1.8ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 356ms (Views: 304.4ms | ActiveRecord: 17.2ms)

Хромоконсоль говорит, что в ответ приходит правильный код для #cart. Вопрос почему #cart нерендерится.

Comment: И наверное Вам надо сделать `destroy.js.erb` а `destroy.html.erb` прибить.